# Jenkins won't execute python subprocess

Tags: python, jenkins, subprocess

I've seen a few suggestions to get around this issue but none of them work for me.

I have Jenkins installed locally on my laptop running Windows10.  I've narrowed it down and it is indeed the line in my python script that's calling subprocess.run method.  The Python scripts executes up to that point so I'm know the script is getting called from the Jenkins job.

It seems to be a permissions error as suggested in other posts.  However, I'm not sure exactly what else I can do.  I log into Windows as Admin so that's not the issue.

The Jenkins job is running as the Jenkins Admin user so I'm not sure what else I can do?

Console output:

```
17:39:21 Started by user admin
17:39:21 Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\loadrunner_test
17:39:21 [loadrunner_test] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins2453008242502676618.bat
17:39:21 
17:39:21 C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\loadrunner_test>cmd /C C:\Python365\python.exe C:\PythonProjects\cicd_loadrunner\cicd_loadrunner.py 
17:44:42 Error:  <class 'subprocess.TimeoutExpired'>
17:44:42 
17:44:42 C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\loadrunner_test>exit -1 
17:44:42 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
17:44:42 Finished: FAILURE
```

When it tries to execute the subprocess.run method, it just hangs and then eventually times out.

When I run the script manually using windows command prompt, it works as expected.

Cheers.

Comment: I think you need to give Jenkins permission to run Python... because jenkins creates a user called jenkins

Comment: I reckon you're right.  Any idea how I do that?  Someone suggested moving the *.boto file into the root but I can't even see a *.boto file (Windows install)

Comment: Glad you got it to work :) I haven't worked on Python much so  *.boto file I have no idea what that is ...:P

Comment: Thanks mate.  Yeah, I have no idea what a .boto file is either :)   Think it's AWS related so was barking up the wrong tree with that one.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end. I had to create a new Windows user which I called JenkinsUser with local admin permissions. I then went into the Jenkins.exe service and am running Jenkins using my new user JenkinsUser.